# unity exits when clicking the play button after adding MRTK packages

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I have a problem in development of mixed reality app and there has been 2 days that I'm stuck.

My problem is that after adding packages of MRTK to the unity project, if I click the play button, the unity exits (closing) without any error massages or warning.

I tested two versions of unity (2020.3.32f1 and 2020.3.33f1) and both had the same problem.
I am using this link ([MRTK document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/1-5-exercise-configure-resources?ns-enrollment-type=learningpath&ns-enrollment-id=learn.azure.beginner-hololens-2-tutorials&tabs=openxr)) and also this one [Mixed Reality Feature Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/welcome-to-mr-feature-tool) as a guide for configuration and adding the packages of MRTK to my project.

I have also tried two different versions of the packages i.e. (Mixed Reality Toolkit Foundation and Mixed Reality Toolkit Extensions both versions of 2.7.3 and 2.7.2 and for Mixed Reality OpenXR Plugin package I tried 1.4.0 and 1.3.1 versions).

I am using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.14

Inside Unity, I am choosing Universal Windows Platform from the Build Settings and I want to  practice a little development of mixed reality applications, but I am stuck at the beginning and when ever I press the play button the unity exits (closed) without any warning or error.

Just for more information → I don't have Microsoft Hololens2, therefor I am considering to use Windows Mixed Reality simulator (Mixed Reality Portal).

I can't get what mistakes I am doing, please if you have any idea help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many steps to configure a Unity Project for Mixed Reality. According to the description, it is hard to determine which step causes the issue. I have created a repository which is implemented with the necessary MR packages, and the configuration has been done. Feel free to pull the repo from https://github.com/sethdu0525/MR-Blank-Project. Please open it and click run to test.

If you still have this issue, you may need to have a clean installation of Unity 2020.3.33f1 (LTS), Visual Studio 2022 and make sure all the required components have been installed, including a comparatively new Windows SDK.

If you have a dump file for the crash, you may also share it and find support from Unity forum -- [General Discussion - Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/forums/general-discussion.14/)

Comment: Well I tried your repo but still had the problem, I verified all the components for visual that are required, Windows SDK etc. but once I try to run a project like your repo, unity closed. I tried your app in another pc, and it was ok and fine, I will  try clean installation with unity hub. (I will uninstall and reinstall again my unity version and the required modules for mixed reality.